# Table design for storing immutable time series telemetry/sensor data?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm looking for some advice on a DynamoDB table design to store telemetry data streaming in from 1000's of sensor hubs. The sensor hubs send up to 15,000 messages per day each, containing the following:

timestamp (unix time)

station_id (uuid)

sensor_type (string)

sensor_data (json)

I've looked into best practices for storing time series data, and will adopt a table partitioning strategy, where a new "hot data" table is created each month (and adjust RCU's and WCU's accordingly for older "cooler" tables).

What i'm not sure about is picking a suitable hash key and sort key, as well as setting up indexes, etc.

The majority of the queries to data will be: Give me messages where station_id = "foo" and sensor_type = "bar", and timestamp is between x and y.

At a guess, i'm assuming I would use station_id as the hash key, and timestamp as the sort key, but how do a query for messages with a particular sensor_type without resorting to filters? Would I be best to combine the station_id and sensor_type as the hash key?

Comment: Is this 15000 evenly distributed over 24h?

Comment: @mayu Yes, correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the query example that you've provided I would do create the following table:

**stationId_sensorType** (String, partition key) - a combined attribute that contains concatenated values for station id and for sensor type

**timestamp** (Number, range key) - UNIX timestamp that you can use to sort by time stamp or to find only record with timestamps in range.

This will allow to get all values for a pair of (stationId, sensorType).

You can also store **stationId** and **sensorType** as separate fields in your items and then you can create GSI on them to support other queries, like, get all values for a **stationId**.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. I've gone ahead and implemented your suggestion and it looks like it will do the job.